# jQuery Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

This is about jQuery Template

I use NuGet to install it. The information is in [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl). So I guess I am using the correct package.

`jQuery.tmpl.min.js` is added and referenced in the `ASP.NET MVC 4` project.

The problem is, when I test using

```
$('#files-list').tmpl(data).appendTo('#Container');
```

It works.

But if I changes to:

```
var t = "div" + tmplName;
$(t).tmpl(data).appendTo('#Container');
```

It fails. And the FireBug gives me some console error like `$(t).tmpl(data).appendTo is not a function`.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot do this? and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like "div" + tmplName is wrong. What does the html look like?  What is the id of the template?

Comment: what is tmplName exactly? Should it be `"div#" + tmplName` or `"div." + tmplName`? Why not just `var t = "#" + tmplName; $(t)....`?

Comment: @Blaise - How you added file in your project? I mean by what keyword I should search in Nuget Package Manager?

Comment: This is a really old post. I am not quite sure if jQuery template has a NuGet package. In the year of 2014, you probably want to add client-side package with bower.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are getting that exception is because you don't have a script block with the id `t` or `"div" + tmplName`. Make sure you have a script block with the passed id.

Ex.

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>
</script>

<script>
var movies = [
    { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
    { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
    { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];

$("#movieTemplate" ).tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieList");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var t = "div" + tmplName;
```

Can never equal to this:

```
'#files-list'
```

Wouldn't you want something more like:

```
var t = '#' + tmplName;
```